# javascript Google scripts create a document within a folder

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I have tried countless techniques, I am NOT able to get

```
DocsList.createFile('example file', 'example file contents');
```

To create a Google Document file. It creates a plain text file.  I have tried adding the mime type. That also does not work- I think may be a bug in google. Whatever file it seems to open in the "viewer"

However is there any workaround, this seems to be fairly simple, I am sure there is a way to do this using?

```
doc = DocumentApp.create('Document Name');
```

I just cant get it into a folder.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can't create files on google app engine itself, only in it's storage (e.g. blobstore or GCS).

Comment: Sorry I dont think I should have tagged Google App Engine- This is a Google Script that will be in a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. Either try using DriveApp (not docsList) to create directly in the folder. If that wont work, create the doc, then add to the folder and remove from root.